# Console scrolling too fast in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am learning how to send a message over a TCP/IP connection in Visual Basic between 2 computers linked by an ethernet cable. When I send the message, the console screen scrolls too far down and the received message no longer shows up on the host computer's console window. When I create a For loop that outputs the message several hundred times I can see the message quickly scrolling through the console window, but at the end the window is left black, which I'm thinking means the window continued to scroll.

I am currently inputing a message into the client console and having the listener console output this message.

Here is my host/listener code:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic


Module Module1

Sub Main()

    'Open listener at port 8
    Dim myHost As New TcpListener(8)
    myHost.Start()
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection")


    Dim myClient As TcpClient = myHost.AcceptTcpClient
    Console.WriteLine("Connected")


    Dim myStream As NetworkStream = myClient.GetStream
    Dim bytes(myClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    Dim receivedMessage As String


    myStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(myClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
    receivedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

    Console.WriteLine("Message was: " & receivedMessage)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Console.ReadLine()

    myClient.Close()
    myHost.Stop()

End Sub

End Module
```

Here is my code for the client, the imports are the same as above:

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()


    Dim myClient As New TcpClient  
    myClient.Connect("My IP", 8)     'Connects to laptop IP on port 8
    Dim myStream As NetworkStream = myClient.GetStream()

    Dim message As String
    message = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("We are sending the read line")
    sendOverIP(message, myStream)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub


Public Sub sendOverIP(ByVal message As String, ByVal myStream As NetworkStream)
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message) 'Turns message into ASCII bytes
    myStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)


    Console.WriteLine("We sent: " & message)
End Sub

End Module
```

I have a breakpoint at this point in the listener

```
    Console.WriteLine("Message was: " & receivedMessage)
```

and as soon as I tell it to continue, the console window becomes all black. I'm assuming that it writes the line then continues to scroll. How can I make it so the received message stays on the console output for the listener?

Comment: Try removing the Thread.Sleep line - that seems redundant to me as you have a ReadLine immediately following that should allow you to see what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are converting the entire `bytes` array to a string in the "host/listener".  You need to convert just the actual bytes that were received, not the whole buffer:

```
Dim actualBytes = myStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
receivedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, actualBytes)
```

Comment: Additionally, it's a better practice to use `bytes.Length` instead of `CInt(myClient.ReceiveBufferSize)`.

Comment: This was the issue, my buffer was too large. Thank you.